# IndexError: pop index out of range

Tags: python, lista

```
def sockMerchant(n, ar):
    cont=0

    for i in range(len(ar)):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if(ar[i] == ar[j]) :
                cont+=1
                ar.pop(i)
                ar.pop(j)


    return cont
```

Me sale el siguiente error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Solution.py", line 18, in sockMerchant
ar.pop(j)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Agradeceria su colaboracion

Comment: Hola kei, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so].  Ten en cuenta que obviamente si eliminas elementos de la lista (`list.pop`) los indices iniciales no serán válidos. Si tienes una lista de 3 elementos y eliminas uno `lista[2]` ya no es un índice válido. Además `i + 1` ya genera un índice inválido cuando `i  == len(ar) - 1` (ultima iteración del for). Por otro lado ¿cual es el comportamiento esperado de la función? ¿Qué es `n` (tampoco puede ser nunca `> len(ar)`)?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿tratas de resolver https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem?